# Fill circle layers with colors according to read values from a plotted curve

Tags: plotting, color, legending, visualization

I want to read (temperature) values from plotted (cooling) curves and visualize them in layered circles.

I have an example made manually for clarification:

3 plotted curves, at certain time steps the value of all plotted curves are read out -> I made a scale assigning (temperature) values to colors.

These colors are used further to color the inner circle (*value from curve "center"*), the mid-layer (*value from curve "half radius"*) and the outer layer (*value from curve "radius"*).

[Data can be found here (csv-file)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfxk8tph6hv2cxd/Data%20visualization%20of%20values.csv?n=113769794)

Thank you for helping me! 
[image]

Comment: yes, thats true, I will remove the color of the curve later.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the position of "sections" or it should be constant?

Comment: Not constant, should be possible to change them.

Comment: @Shukoff Please do not accept my answer so quickly. I did not manage to finish it and when you accept my answer you dissuade others from giving it a try!

Comment: @C. E.: ok, makes sense. Thanx!

Comment: In my opinion the question about "how to reverse the order of a horizontal `BarLegend`" should be a new, separate question. It is a perfectly good stand-alone problem, and really completely unrelated to this "fill circle layers with colors" question, except that you personally happen to want both features on one chart.

Comment: Also, editing your question to include completely new requirements *after* receiving two very good answers is a little rude to those who spent time and effort writing those answers.

Comment: @Simon: Thank you for your comment. I am just on the way to get familiar with the conventions here. Of course I will start a new separate question.I am very grateful to the two very good answers and will highly regard their work!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for listening! The best way to get familiar with the site is to browse through some of the other questions and answers. Don't forget to upvote any you think are useful, and of course share your own knowledge by answering any questions you can. If you have any questions about the site's policies and conventions you can ask them on the [meta site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not the prettiest, perhaps, but I just wanted to finish what I started. I was able to finish it after having read ssch excellent answer and see how he used `Offset`. This plot was truly a challenge to me, and the problem is in combining the different graphics. Had I tried this again I would probably do everything with `Graphics` and not use `ListLinePlot` at all.

```
(*Time;Temperature center;Temperature half radius;Temperature radius*)
data = Rest /@ 
   Import["~/Downloads/mmadata.csv", "Table", 
    "FieldSeparators" -> ";"];
timeseries = Transpose[data];

(*Where to sample*)
samplepts = {500, 1000, 1500};

(*Generate disk*)

temperatureDisk[pt_, data_, r_] := Module[{colordata},
  colordata = 
   Reverse[ColorData[
      "TemperatureMap"] /@ ((data[[pt]] - 15)/(32 - 15))];
  MapIndexed[{#, 
     Disk[Offset[{0, -3 r}, {pt, Min[data]}], 
      Offset[(r/3) (4 - First@#2)]]} &, colordata]
  ]

p = ListLinePlot[timeseries, GridLines -> {samplepts, {}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Dashed];

g = Graphics[temperatureDisk[#, data, 10] & /@ samplepts];

legend = SwatchLegend[
   ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Flatten[{0, (Range[10]/10), 32}],
   Flatten[{"< 15", Round[(32 - 15) (Range[10]/10) + 14], "> 32"}],
   LegendLayout -> "Column"
   ];

GraphicsRow[{
  Show[
   p,
   g,
   PlotRange -> {{0, Length[First[timeseries]]}, {Min[data], 
      Max[data]}},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, Min[data]},
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {40, All}}
   ],
  legend
  }, Spacings -> 0, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: scrn]

Comment: in a second step: is there an easy way to create a table from the colored circles from different such graphs (circles of each graph per row; header: "experiment", samplept1, samplept2,...)?

Comment: @Shukoff Yes, it should be easy. All you need is the `temeperatureDisk` function and `TableForm` or possibly `GraphicsGrid`. `TableForm` is better if you want headers. You can turn the output into an image using `Rasterize`.

Comment: And how to insert a horizontal BarLegend for TemperatureColors below the temperatureDisk with the temperature on it decreasing from left to right?

Comment: @Shukoff I'm not good at combining graphics like this but you could try to wrap the entire thing with `GraphicsColumn`. The risk is you will get a large white space in between the plot and the bar, which perhaps could be fixed by playing with `AspectRatio` and perhaps not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, helped very much!

Answer (score 10):

(This answer has just the circles, not the box with color scale information)

To get circular looking disks I use [`Offset[r]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Offset.html) for the radius, which ignores aspect-ratio and plot scale:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 30}, AspectRatio -> 1/10, Epilog -> {
   {Red, Circle[{5, 5}, 5]},
   {Green, Circle[{20, 20}, Offset[10]]}
   }]
```

[image]

When putting `Graphics` together with `Show` the `Axes` will also extend, I avoid this with [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePadding.html) Which also allows to put everything in `Epilog`:

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 30}];
GraphicsRow[{
  Show[{p, Graphics[{Disk[{15, -15}, Offset[10]]}]},
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   PlotRange -> All],
  Show[p,
   Epilog -> {Disk[{15, -15}, Offset[10]]},
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {50, All}}]
  }]
```

[image: axes]

This function takes a `Graphics` object and a list of x-values as argument and for each curve (`Line`) makes a disk layer.

The list wrangling became quite ugly, if you need clarification on some parts just ask.

```
ClearAll[circleLayer]
Options[circleLayer] = {
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["Temperature"],
   "Radius" -> 10};
circleLayer[g_Graphics, ind_List, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
   fns = Cases[g, l_Line :> Interpolation[l[[1]]], Infinity],
   plotRange = (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]),
   fpts, pts, lines, colorF, rmax
   },
  {rmax, colorF} = OptionValue[{"Radius", ColorFunction}];

  fpts = MapIndexed[
     {ConstantArray[rmax (1 - First[#2]/(Length[fns] + 1)), Length[ind]],
      ind, #[ind]}\[Transpose] &,
     fns
     ]~Flatten~1;
  (* Lines from curves to disks *)
  lines = {Dashed, Line[
     (x \[Function] {Offset[{0, -1.5 rmax}, {x, plotRange[[2, 1]]}],
                    {x, Max[Through[fns[x]]]}}) /@ ind ]};
  (* points on curve *)
  pts = {Gray, Disk[#, Offset[rmax/5]] & /@ fpts[[All, 2 ;; 3]]};

  If[OptionValue[ColorFunctionScaling],
   fpts[[All, 3]] = Rescale[fpts[[All, 3]]]
   ];

  Show[g,
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {4 rmax, All}},
   Epilog -> {
     EdgeForm[Black],
     pts, lines,
     Function[{r, x, y},
       {colorF[y],
        Disk[
         Offset[{0, -3 rmax}, {x, plotRange[[2, 1]]}],
         Offset[r]
         ]}] @@@ fpts}]]
```

Example:

```
circleLayer[
 Plot[{x, x^2, Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}],
 {-1/3, 1/3, 2/3, 1}]
```

[image: example]

For the linked data you get something like:

[image: listplot]

Comment: how to insert the scaled PlotLegend? and how to color the line around the circles and its layers with the corresponding color (removal of the black circle lines)?

Comment: @Shukoff Get rid of `EdgeForm` to remove the borders. For the legend (assuming you don't mean just text) you need to build it yourself and then `Show` it together with the plot or put it in the `Epilog`.

Comment: Just a tiny remark, I find usefult to create disks with `Point` + `PointSize` to not worry about ratios.

Comment: @Kuba Oh quite right, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @ssch `Offset[10]` is interesting - is this usage documented? In the help, it only gives `Offset[{dx,dy},position]` and I would never guess what giving a single number would do... :)

Comment: @cormullion I believe I saw it somewhere, but now I can only find the `Offset[{rx, ry}]` ellipse specification. Too bad there is no way to search the documentation for `Offset[(_?NumericQ|_Symbol)]` :)

Comment: @ssch: Thank you very much for your answer which contributed very much to the solution.

Comment: @Kuba: Thank you for your remarks!

Answer (score 2):

Like Anon, I didn't know about the `Offset` option, which turned out to be useful. I didn't finish my attempt, but here is how far I got - and with the use of `Offset`. I was interested in whether it was possible to do the job with a single `ListLinePlot` command. I'm not sure it is (there's still work to do with scaling the disks somehow), but this is as close as I got:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {data[[2 ;; -1, {1, 2}]], data[[2 ;; -1, {1, 3}]], 
  data[[2 ;; -1, {1, 4}]]},
 PlotRange -> {{-50, 2100}, {-5, 35}},
 PlotStyle ->  {Red, Blue, Purple},
 ImageSize -> 800, ImagePadding -> 25,
 Epilog -> Table[
   {xcenter, ycenter} = data[[x, {1, 2}]]; 
   yhalfradius = data[[x, 3]];
   yradius = data[[x, 4]];
   {
    Thin, Red,
    Line[{{xcenter, -3}, {xcenter, ycenter}}],
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[ycenter, {1, 30}]],
    Disk[{xcenter, -3}, Offset[Rescale[ycenter, {1, 4}]]],
    Disk[{xcenter, ycenter}, Offset[3]],
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[yhalfradius, {1, 30}]],
    Disk[{xcenter, -3},   Offset[Rescale[yhalfradius, {1, 4}]]],
    Disk[{xcenter, yhalfradius}, Offset[3]],
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[yradius, {1, 30}]],
    Disk[{xcenter, -3}, Offset[Rescale[ yradius, {1, 4}]]],
    Disk[{xcenter, yradius}, Offset[3]]
    },
   {x,   {2, 252, 501, 1001, 1501, 2001}}],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[data[[1, 2 ;;]], {0.75, 0.85}]
 ]
```

[image: plot]